# Java Android Get the name of a collection from the firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to show all posts from users followed and I'm using a Recyclerview:

```
  FirestoreRecyclerOptions<GetInfoPost> options
                = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<GetInfoPost>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("following").document(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).collection("/userFollowing").limit(1000), GetInfoPost.class)
                .build();

        FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<GetInfoPost, FindFriendsViewHolder> firestoreRecyclerAdapter

                =new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<GetInfoPost, FindFriendsViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendsViewHolder findFriendsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull GetInfoPost getInfoPost) {

                final String listUserId = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(i).getId();

                Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                        .collection("post/" + listUserId + "/userPosts")
                        .limit(1000);

                query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(1);
                        final String postId = snapshot.getId();

                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("posts/" + listUserId + "/userPosts").document(postId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                findFriendsViewHolder.txtDescrizione.setText(task.getResult().getString("description"));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });






            }
```

As you can see I'm trying to get the description field from the last post, the problem is that I don't know the id of the last post. The post id is nothing more than the name of a collection and I want to be able to pick it up.

In the code shown above I tried to get it like this:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                        .collection("post/" + listUserId + "/userPosts")
                        .limit(1);

                query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(1);
                        final String postId = snapshot.getId();
```

but I get a null description because the query does not open the name of the collection, but goes to get followers (even if I'm not sure enough about this). Is there a way to get the name of the first collection that the query finds? for example this:

[image]

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can get the last added document.

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm not trying to get the last document in a Firebase collection but Get the name of a collection so I don't know how to set the orderby because it wouldn't make sense